# What is the right way to update a table view in a Part in a Eclipse RCP project?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, e4

Say I have a `ItemListPart` class in my RCP project, and there is a table to be displayed in it as following:

```
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

import org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.Focus;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Table;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableColumn;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TableItem;

public class ItemListPart {
    private Table table;

    @PostConstruct 
    public void createControls(Composite parent){
      //I wish the ItemList could be changed from outside the ItemListPart class.
      List<Item> ItemList = getItemList();

      parent.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));

      table = new Table(parent, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BORDER | SWT.FULL_SELECTION);
      table.setLinesVisible(true);
      table.setHeaderVisible(true);
      GridData data = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true);
      data.heightHint = 200;
      table.setLayoutData(data);

      String[] titles = { "Item Name", "Description"};
      for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
          TableColumn column = new TableColumn(table, SWT.NONE);
          column.setText(titles[i]);
          table.getColumn(i).pack();
      }


      for(Item it:ItemList){
          TableItem item = new TableItem(table, SWT.NONE);
          item.setText(0, it.getName());
          item.setText(1, it.getDesc());
      }

      for (int i=0; i<titles.length; i++) {
          table.getColumn (i).pack ();
      }
    }

    @Focus
    public void onFocus() {
        table.setFocus();
    }
}
```

Here the `ItemList<Item>` is a List which I wish could be changed from outside the `ItemListPart` class, and whenever the data in `ItemList<Item>` changed, the table view could be auto refreshed according to the updated data. What is the right way to achieve this goal? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no one 'correct' way.

One way is to use the event broker and have your view part listen for events from the code which updates the list.

In the code which updates the list post an event:

```
@Inject
IEventBroker eventBroker;

...

eventBroker.post("/list/updated", Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
```

In your view listen for the update event:

```
@Inject
@Optional
public void listUpdated(@UIEventTopic("/list/updated") Event event)
{
  // TODO handle the update
}
```

Note: `Event` is `org.osgi.service.event.Event`.

You will probably find it easier to use `TableViewer` rather than `Table` as the separate content provider makes it much easier to update the table for content changes.

You can also pass data in the event using something like:

```
MyClass myClass = ....

eventBroker.post("/list/updated", myClass);


@Inject
@Optional
public void listUpdated(@UIEventTopic("/list/updated") MyClass myClass)
```

There is some more information on event brokers [here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Eclipse4EventSystem/article.html)

Comment: Thank you.  In your code sample, is `Collections.EMPTY_MAP` the data passed for view to update? If so, how could I get the data in method `listUpdated(@UIEventTopic("/list/updated") Event event)`?

Comment: Yes, I have added an example passing some data in the event to the answer.

Comment: Can you please clarify whether the code that post the event and the the code that listens should be in separate thread? Should the eventBroker.post must be in non UI thread?

Comment: @SaminathanS `eventBroker.post` can be on any thread. Using `@UIEventTopic` for the listener will ensure that method runs in the UI thread.

Comment: @greg-449 I have kept the both posting and receiving in same thread, unable to receive the events. Does it help if we keep one of them in another thread?

Comment: @SaminathanS Threads make no difference. If you are using the `Event` class make sure it is `org.osgi.service.event.Event`

Comment: Thanks @greg-449 for the clarification. It is actually the parameter value that has made the event not to be received. Also, found that event that are sent with primitives (in the place of MyClass) are not received.